# Using ant to run easyB stories in parallel

Tags: easyb

How do I pass the switch to run scenarios\stories in parallel to the **ant** task ?

Side Q:
Does it run scenarios in parallel ? or stories ?
How do I configure number of the threads etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

For running easyb in background: ants `parallel` task is the right point to look at: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html

EasyB seems to **not support** the parallel execution of stories/scenarios in Ant at the moment.
In Maven and from Console it should work. 
See http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/07/21/useful-tricks-easyb-tags-and-parallel-tests